# Spiderman Web of Shadows black screen

Tags: technical-issues, spiderman-web-of-shadows

After playing the game for a while, the game stops and the screen turns black. What should I do to fix this? I also get the problem when spidey goes too high in the air.

Comment: what platform are you playing on? if PC, what are your system specs? does it happen at a particular point in the game play?

Comment: Please don't start every word with a capital, that is very annoying to read. I fixed it for you in this question.

Comment: I have Intel HD Grahics Family, Windows 7 SP1 32 bit, 4 Gb Ram. I Just Played It From the Beginning And It Stopped In The First Video Where Spidey Swing Along The Road And Sees Symboites. Plz Help Me.

Comment: I tried everything I could but still. I installed the patch, Then also the problem was not going. Do I have to download an Original Version. I Thing The System Requirements Are quite near with the once I told.

Comment: What do you mean by "download an original version"?

Comment: Original Version means downloading a no rip game. Coz I have JPN Ripped Version. Anyway Do You Have Any Solution ?

Comment: I Tried Reinstalling It But Not Solved

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved many months ago. I just updated my graphics card driver and it worked.